# powershell smo login move

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

Is it possible to create a Powershell script that moves the login from a source server to a destination server - including the current password?
I tried to use the `sp_help_revlogin` procedure, but I'm unable to get the t-sql output into a variable.

```
$handler = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventHandler] {param($sender, $event) $LoginDes = $event.Message };
$smoSrc.connectionContext.add_InfoMessage($handler);
$smoSrc.connectionContext.executeNonQuery("EXEC master..sp_help_revlogin $dbLogin")
```

If a try to use the `script()` method, the code generated has the password field but is not the sid value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passwords have been troublesome with powershell historically, but you can get the SID if you use the script method and pass in a custom ScriptingOptions object.

```
$so = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions;
$so.LoginSid = $true
$login.script( $so );
```